# Read and write a file offsite? (Replit)

Tags: file, file-writing, replit, offsite

so as the title says, I need to find a way to **read** and **write** a file **offsite** from **[Replit](http://replit.com)**, so I can use it in Roblox for example (of course not only in Roblox).